# I keep getting blank value and an invalid file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [it inserts a blank value for ImageId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044822/it-inserts-a-blank-value-for-imageid)

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPtMq/25/) where the user is able to add a question in a textarea and add the question underneath. Now when the user adds a question, it adds the question in a table below but it also adds a column which contains a file input. The user can select a image file using this input.

Now I have not included a submit button in the Jsfiddle but when the user submits the form, it will take the user to the create_session.php page but I have an AJAX underneath where it will post to the insertQuestion.php in the background.

```
  function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });  
    alert("Your Details for this Session has been submitted"); 
}
```

Now in the insertQuestion.php, it does two things, first of all it should upload all the files from the file input field and it should insert all of the values from the form into the database.

There are 2 problems though:

Problem 1:

It keeps echoing I have an 'Invalid File' even though i am uploading a correct file type. Why is it doing this and how can it be fixed so it doesn't echo 'Invalid file' for valid files.

Problem 2:

In the INSERT VALUES code, it keeps displaying a blank value for the 'ImageId' even when a file location has been chosen from the file input. Why does it keep dislaying a blank value and how can this be fixed?

Below is an example of the INSERT VALUES I am currently seeing:

```
INSERT INTO Question (QuestionContent, ImageId) VALUES ('What is my Name?',''), ('What is my Age','')
```

Below is the full code in the insertQuestion.php:

```
<?php

session_start();


 if ((($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/tif")))
  {
  if ($_FILES["fileImage"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileImage"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["fileImage"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp fileImage: " . $_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("uploadimages/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploadimages/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploadimages/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }


$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


$i = 0;
    $c = count($_POST['questionText']);

    $insertquestion = array();

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

      $imagequery = "SELECT ImageId FROM Image WHERE (ImageFile = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fileImage'])."')";
        $imagers = mysql_query($imagequery);
        $imagerecord = mysql_fetch_array($imagers);
        $imageid = $imagerecord['ImageId']; 

        $insertquestion[] = "'".  
                        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['questionText'][$i] ) ."','".
                        mysql_real_escape_string( $imageid [$i] ) ."'";

    }

     $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, QuestionMarks, OptionId, ImageId) 
        VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

    echo($questionsql);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
Since you're adding [] to the upload file name $_FILES["fileImage"] is an array of Files and so ["type"] only exists for each element of the array, so the if fails.

error_reporting(E_ALL);
 helps against this kind of errors.

Problem 2 is Problem 1 but with $_POST